# jQuery $.fn.whatever no longer working on live server

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I hate posting questions without code, but if I knew what to post I'd know the problem.

**All of my jquery plugin functions have stopped working on the live server.**

They still work locally, and all of the external javascript files should be the same.

I get the message `$(...).whatever is not a function` on all of them. I'm not sure what I changed that caused this.. the file is being detected and I did not do anything to affect the scope.

Any ideas?

Comment: Silly me. Including AJAX loaded content that contains conflicting scripting. Freaked me out. Guess I'd better remove that script since it's just for a visual representation of actual item.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a rather annoying problem that will no doubt be faced later on by others, here is a bit more details on the cause and solution of this problem.

**Problem:** I was loading in content that contained `<script></script>` that broke my master page by loading javascript (jQuery really) that conflicted with it. It rendered my custom plugins useless.

**Solution:** Simply render the `script` blocks useless for the AJAX loaded content. Here's how.

## How to remove `<script>` blocks from AJAX loaded content:

I tried a couple of different methods, but in the end this one proved the most reliable:

```
$.ajax(url,{
  success: function(data){
    data = data.replace(/<script(?:.*)>/gi,'<!--[Script Removed]>>>');
    data = data.replace(/<\/script>/gi,'<<<[Script Removed]-->');
    $('.faux-container').html(data);
 }
});
```

It converts the `<script>` blocks into harmless HTML comments, and solved my issue.